# Prove recursive sequence is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given $u_1=1/4$ and $u_{n+1}=2u_n(1-u_n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, prove $\{u_n\}$ is convergent.

**Attempt:** I know I have to prove $\{u_n\}$ is monotone and bounded. What I've tried:

- Bounded: As a first guess, $0< u_n \le 1/2$, then
  $$1/2 \le 1-u_n<1$$
  $$u_n\le 2u_n(1-u_n) <2u_n$$
  $$u_n\le u_{n+1} < 2u_n$$
  and I get monotony, but not boundness because $0<u_{n+1}<1$ and not $1/2$ as expected (I could do this $m$ times and get $0<u_{n+m}<2^{m-1}$).
- Monotony: $p(n): u_{n+1}>u_n$. For $n=1$ it's true, assume there's a $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p(k)$ is true. I have many ideas here but, if I start from $p(k+1)$ and try to get something using $p(k)$ I get boundness. If I start from $p(k)$ and try to get $p(k+1)$ I get something like
  $$2u_k(1-u_{k+1})<u_{k+1}$$
  which is not usefull.

Any hint would be great!

**Let's assume I don't have calculus tools, like derivatives.**

Comment: $0<u_n<1/2\implies-1/2<u_n-1/2<0\implies 0<(u_n-1/2)^2<1/4\implies-1/2<-2(u_n-1/2)^2<0\implies 0<-2(u_n-1/2)^2+1/2<1/2$.

Comment: Analyze the function $f(u)=2u(1-u)$ on $[0,1]$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $2u_n(1-u_n)$ has a maximum value of $\frac{1}{2}$ when $u_n=\frac 1 2$.

And if $0 < u_n < \frac 1 2$ then $1-u_n > \frac 1 2$ so  $u_{n+1} > u_n$.

So if $u_0 = \frac 1 4$ then $\{u_n\}$ is increasing and bounded above by $\frac 1 2$.

Answer (score 0):

$u_1=\frac{1}{4}$, $u_2=2u_1(1-u_1)=\frac{1}{2}\big(1-\frac{1}{2^{2^1}}\big)$.

Now $u_3=2u_2(1-u_2)=2.\frac{1}{2}\big(1-\frac{1}{2^{2^1}}\big)\big(1-\frac{1}{2}\big(1-\frac{1}{2^{2^1}}\big)\big)=\big(1-\frac{1}{2^{2^1}}\big)\big(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^{2^1+1}}\big)=\frac{1}{2}\big(1-\frac{1}{2^{2^2}}\big)$.

Inductively we can prove $u_n=\frac{1}{2}\big(1-\frac{1}{2^{2^{n-1}}}\big)$. Therefore $\{u_n\}$ converges to $\frac{1}{2}$.